# Obtaining JSON data from server into $.ajax call

Tags: json

I have a problem with JSON and JQUERY. In my web application I submit some data (through an $.ajax call) to a servlet and want to receive back some informations from this servlet once it has done.
I'm using JSONObject in this way:

```
function check(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/check",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: on_check_ok,
        error: function(){
            alert("something wrong happened");
            },
        data: { 
            players_code: $("#players_code").val(),  
            },
        });
    return false;
}
function on_check_ok(data) {
    var json = data;
    $("#display").text(json.check);  //"display" is a <div> into index.html
    };
```

and this is doPost() method in my servlet code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
   response.setContentType("application/json");
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   String code_array = request.getParameter("players_code");
   System.out.println("Player's code is: " + code_array);
   int arr = Integer.parseInt(code_array);
   LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();
   while(arr > 0){
                stack.push(arr%10);  
                arr = arr/10;
   }
   int index = 0;
   while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        array[index] = (int)stack.pop();
        index++;    
   }
   mm.checkGuess(array);
   response.getWriter().write(mm.ris + " ");
   tries++;
   System.out.println("TRIES: " + tries);
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
   obj.put("check", tries);
   String json = obj.toString();
   out.write(json);
   System.out.println("JSON " + json);
```

}
}

but cannot get displayed any information. Seems that JSONObject has been created correctly, since I can display it on console. I'm having hard times on getting this data back to javascripts. 
That's my code, what I'm doing wrong? Or, is there an alternative way to get the same result? thanks for the help!

Comment: "but cannot get displayed any information" ? are you telling that you are not able to get properties of JSON object  or the entire response is nil..

Comment: @Dave when printing on console I can see all the data I got from methods invoked inside the servlet. So as far as I understood, the JSON objects is good. I suppose there's something wrong in my javascript code. I tried several examples found on the net and my code is not so different. But mine doesn't work...I'm confused..

Comment: i doubt on this line "$("#display").text(json.check); "   instead try this line $("#display").text(data);  just to check if DIV is getting populated ? and also make sure div with id="display" is present :)

Comment: @Dave tried your suggestion. got no response. Instead I tried to add some error message displayed (on #display) and...got error message..A question: is it possible to make an ajax call and send to a servlet some data (which is NOT Json) and receive Json data back?